# Why react arrow function component gives error in React with Laravel?

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm using React with laravel. With Inertia, arrow function doesn't seem to work. Why?

```
import React from "react";

export default function All() {
    return <div>All</div>;
}
```

this code works but

```
export const All = () => {
  return (
    <div>All</div>
  )
}
```

this code doesn't work. It displays an error.

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `Inertia`.
```

Comment: Did you update the import accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

see this is a All.js file where the code is look like below

```
export const All = () => {
    return <div>All</div>;
};
```

and this is App.js file where the app component is set

```
import { All } from "./All";

<div>
 <All />
</div>
```

whenever you export arrow function like above then you have to import that component like below

```
import { componentName } from 'path';
```

Comment: with "export default All" added at the bottom of file, it worked. Thanks anyway. :)